# Cliente BigQuery para Android

Tags: android

Alguém sabe se existe algum cliente do BigQuery para Android? Preciso realizar consultas de tabelas no BigQuery.

Olhei na documentação do google é diz:

Observação: atualmente, as bibliotecas de cliente Java para Google Cloud não são compatíveis com Android.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries

Alguém tem alguma ideia de outra alternativa?

Comment: Fala @Lucas! Será que no seu caso não é melhor criar uma aplicação web para você consumir os dados via rest?

Comment: Opá tudo bem. Então, na verdade estava pensando em fazer isso. Mas não sei como posso começar com isso. Dei uma olhadana documentação da API de referência do google. Mas não entendi muito bem. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/

Comment: Preciso consumir esses dados em android, ios e web

Comment: Se você tá pensando fazer o Android comunicar diretamente o BigQuery por rest, então segue um documento que vai te dar uma ideia a respeito do assunto: https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/android-from-scratch-using-rest-apis--cms-27117

Comment: Mas eu criaria um orquestrador (um aplicativo Java Web em Spring Boot) que faria a comunicação com o BigQuery (utilizando a biblioteca BigQuery client disponível no anunciado) e a comunicação do Android com minha aplicação faria em Rest.

Comment: Estou olhando, o documento que você me mandou. Muito bom. Vou dar uma olhada e estudar pela forma do orquestrador. Obrigado!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87329/discussion-between-carlos-mesquita-aguiar-and-lucas-cordeiro).

Comment: Se o post te ajudou, situe a resposta correta.